# Conflict between wildcard DNS entry and SPF

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, amazon-route53

I have a domain set up on Amazon's Route53, and it seems the following entries are not going to work (actual values replaced, obviously). Can anyone advise on how this *should* be set up?

This is the initial setup, which is working fine:

```
sub.example.com.        A       1.2.3.4
*.sub.example.com.  CNAME   sub.example.com.
```

This allows us to use a URL like `dave.sub.example.com/pages` and have Apache rewrite that to `sub.domain.com/users/dave/pages`.

I then went to add a TXT record for SPF:

```
sub.example.com.        TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all"
```

But now Mandrill is reporting this error:

```
We found a record named sub.example.com.sub.example.com. Try changing it to sub.example.com.
```

My (uneducated) guess is that the `CNAME` record is trumping the `TXT` record. Is there some way to have these co-exist peacefully and preserve the `*.sub.example.com` rewriting?

Comment: Can you give us the actual domain so we can check the SPF record?

Comment: Another user with similar symptom: http://railwayman.smallpict.com/

Comment: The domain is caps.hub.ki (note there is also a real hub.ki domain if that's important). @masegaloeh It's not clear from that link whether that user had copied the entire DNS entry (mandrill._domainkey.culverden.org), which is what Mandrill says to do, into the Route53 console. If they had, then Route53 also adds the current hosted zone suffix, and they'd have ended up with literally mandrill._domainkey.culverden.org.culverden.org in DNS. The next bullet point suggests they then entered it correctly and the problem was resolved. I _think_ that's a different problem to what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I would say that your configuration is fine. At least if your TXT record does in fact have a trailing dot as it does in your example.

The most likely scenario is that Mandrill is checking for a variant of `sub.example.com.` that is missing its trailing dot, with the expectation that it is a typo. While you do not have a `sub.example.com.sub.example.com.` record per se, the `*.sub.example.com.` wildcard `CNAME` makes it *appear* that you do because its target has a TXT record defined.

If you want this error to go away without changing your existing wildcard functionality, you can try invalidating the scope of the wildcard:

`sub.example.com.sub.example.com. A 192.0.2.0`

This should prevent wildcard expansion from matching `sub.example.com.sub.example.com.`, as a record already exists with that scope. Since it's not a TXT record, this will prevent Mandrill from matching a TXT record with that name.

This isn't a pretty hack, but your only real alternative is to nudge Mandrill into not complaining about this.

Comment: Yes, the entries do end with a dot, according to the Route53 display. I'll contact Mandrill and ask them to check out this thread. They're normally pretty responsive. Tx.

Comment: Putting the correct SPF entry in allowed Mandrill to validate the domain, and they're going to look at fixing their web interface to report the error differently.